# Using local package in React Native project not working

Tags: react-native, npm, package.json, metro-bundler

I need to install my local package in my react-native project.

I install the package using `npm i /path-to-folder` command

But i get this error `Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault`

local package package.json

```
{
 ...
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.4",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.2.0"
  }
}
```

project's metro-config.js

```
resolver: {
  nodeModulesPaths: [packagePath],
},
watchFolders: [packagePath],
```